# Use of Append for Backup Exec 10.1d - Two Jobs to One Tape

Tags: backup, backupexec

We are running a Windows 2003 SBS server and Backup Exec 10.1d

We currently have one job which backs up both hard drives then the exchange server, but recently we have had problems with VSS complaining about the Advanced Open File Option and the popular recommendation for this situation was to split the job down the middle and have data and exchange separate.

This I have no problem doing however I need to get a backup to tape every night of everything so cant do data night 1 and exchange night 2 as it would be impractical and leaves us with an every other day backup.

I have seen the append option mentioned in backup exec a few times in the options and im really wondering if it works how i think it could, in other words back up two seperate jobs to the same tape.

For example,

1. Backup Data (no eject after job completes)
2. Backup Exchange
3. Eject Tape.

If this is possible then should I set the Data job to overwrite tape in job setup then for exchange choose append or terminate?

All Together the backup works out to about 101gb, and the drive is an HP LTO1 drive (100/200GB) so thee is room to get everything on there but obviously having not used append before I wasnt sure if this was a supported operation.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your plan. Have the first backup to tape job overwrite the tape and have the second backup to tape job append/terminate if not appendable. The worst that will happen is it will prompt for another tape during the second job if it runs out of appendable media (tape).

Comment: thanks, managed to get a chance to set up a demo job and seems to work OK, so have configured tonight jobs to run the same with separate data/exchange backups, just wanted to sanity check it as I had never used append before :)

Comment: Glad to help...